# Animating multiple SVG paths on scroll with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I'm trying to extend the JS from this Codrops article:

https://tympanus.net/Development/StorytellingMap/

I'm attempting to animate multiple SVG lines to "split" the SVG path. To simulate it I created multiple paths overlaid on one another. The pertinent SVG code is as such ([for reference, example](https://i.imgur.com/d8S6SVn.png)):

```
<g id="trail-path" display="none">
    <path display="inline" d="M1058.75,817.41a159.76,159.76,0,0,0,11.15-18.24c1.16-2.23,2.31-4.72,1.75-7.17-.64-2.81-3.29-4.65-5.8-6.06a77.9,77.9,0,0,0-29.34-9.42c-4.94-.55-10-.63-14.73-2.09s-9-4.25-13.21-7Q982,749.77,956.19,731.08c-5.52-4-6.81-10.78-7.54-17.56s-1.07-14-5.05-19.56c-6.48-9-20-10.06-27.26-18.47-6.31-7.34-6.07-18.23-4-27.69.83-3.83,1.91-7.67,1.73-11.59-.33-7-4.6-13.1-8.71-18.77-5.63-7.76-11.87-16-21-18.91-6-1.91-10.76-6.9-15-11.53s-8.06-9.68-12.69-13.93c-6-5.48-13.25-9.54-18.62-15.63-6.34-7.2-9.47-16.58-13-25.51-.94-2.38-2.11-5-4.46-6-10.45-4.59-20.41-11.33-27.17-20.53-3.37-4.58-5.63-9.85-7.87-15.07-2.61-6.1-5.27-12.39-5.4-19-.17-8.82,4.17-17.39,3.26-26.16-.5-4.79-2.53-9.26-4.53-13.64l-15.15-33.08 
M1058.75,817.41a159.76,159.76,0,0,0,11.15-18.24c1.16-2.23,2.31-4.72,1.75-7.17-.64-2.81-3.29-4.65-5.8-6.06a77.9,77.9,0,0,0-29.34-9.42c-4.94-.55-10-.63-14.73-2.09s-9-4.25-13.21-7Q982,749.77,956.19,731.08c-5.52-4-6.81-10.78-7.54-17.56s-1.07-14-5.05-19.56c-6.48-9-20-10.06-27.26-18.47-6.31-7.34-6.07-18.23-4-27.69,2.67-12.28-.83-25.88,6.72-36.71,3.74-5.37,9.15-9.33,13.36-14.35,11.71-14,12.1-36.16.89-50.53-7.54-9.65-19.06-15.39-27.38-24.38-5.24-5.66-9.07-12.45-12.85-19.17" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="5"/>
</g>
```

I'm 90% sure that the code I should primarily be focusing on is here. I just need a way to iterate it for each path component. I'm looking at "t.trailPath" and the path contained within "#trail-path." I initially tried multiple grouped path elements and iterating them but it didn't work (and rightfully so since I realized that was the wrong approach).

```
(0, p.default)(this.props.mapSrc).then(function(e) {
                        t.mapSVG = Array.from((new DOMParser).parseFromString(e, "image/svg+xml").childNodes).filter(function(t) {
                            var e = t.tagName;
                            return "undefined" == typeof e ? !1 : "svg" == e.toLowerCase()
                        })[0], t.cameraPath = t.mapSVG.querySelector("#camera-path path"), t.trailPath = t.mapSVG.querySelector("#trail-path path"), t.points = Array.from(t.mapSVG.querySelectorAll("#points circle")).map(function(e) {
                            var i = parseFloat(e.getAttribute("cx")),
                                r = parseFloat(e.getAttribute("cy"));
                            return {
                                x: i,
                                y: r,
                                length: d.getLengthAtPoint(t.trailPath, {
                                    x: i,
                                    y: r
                                }),
                                label: (e.getAttribute("id") || "").replace(/_/g, " "),
                                color: e.getAttribute("fill") || "black",
                                radius: parseFloat(e.getAttribute("r"))
                            }
                        }).sort(function(t, e) {
                            return t.length - e.length
                        }), t.cameraSubdivisions = d.subdividePath(t.cameraPath, t.cameraSubdivisionSize, !0), t.cameraLength = d.getLength(t.cameraPath), t.cameraBreakpoints = t.setupBreakpoints(t.cameraPath), t.trailSubdivisions = d.subdividePath(t.trailPath, t.trailSubdivisionSize, !0), t.trailBreakpoints = t.setupBreakpoints(t.trailPath), t.trailLength = d.getLength(t.trailPath), (0, l.loadImage)(t.props.mapSrc).then(function(e) {
                            t.mapWidth = e.width, t.mapHeight = e.height, 0 == t.mapHeight && (t.mapWidth = 2040, t.mapHeight = 1178), t.map = b(t.mapScales).map(function(i, r) {
                                var n = 1 + (t.mapMaxScale - 1) / (t.mapScales - 1) * r,
                                    s = (0, h.default)(t.mapWidth * n, t.mapHeight * n),
                                    a = s.getContext("2d", {
                                        alpha: !1
                                    });
                                return a.fillStyle = "#a8cecf", a.fillRect(0, 0, t.mapWidth * n, t.mapHeight * n), a.drawImage(e, 0, 0, t.mapWidth * n, t.mapHeight * n), {
                                    map: s,
                                    scale: n
                                }
                            }), t.mapBuffer = (0, h.default)(1, 1), t.mapBufferCtx = t.mapBuffer.getContext("2d", {
                                alpha: !1
                            }), t.updateMapBufferSize(), t.mapBufferCtx.fillStyle = "#a8cecf", t.mapBufferCtx.fillRect(0, 0, t.mapBufferSize.x, t.mapBufferSize.y), t.mapBufferOffset = {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0
                            }, t.mapBufferScale = t.mapScale, t.ready = !0, document.addEventListener("scroll", t.onScroll.bind(t)), t.onScroll()
                        })
                    })
```

The site for reference. It's not updated to include attempts as obviously it breaks it. It focuses on Giarratana alongside Chiaramonte as it should, but no dice on getting the path traced or highlighted.

https://adrianatwell.github.io/bond-of-strangers/code/html/

The code is here for reference. It's 6.5K lines though so it wouldn't be much help.

https://github.com/adrianatwell/bond-of-strangers/blob/master/code/html/assets/js/app.js

I'm way in over my head with this script it seems, I've been tooling around with it and Google for the past 72 hours. Haha.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. You haven't really explained what you mean by "split the path".  It looks like the trail forks at "Ragusa", what do you want to happen then?

Comment: Well... Nothing. The path ends there but the primary path continues on. I realize this question was poorly worded and I'm an idiot, as the source files are ES 2015. I was looking at the compiled JavaScript file.